# Split Date Range in months SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split date range in months. I will pass startdate(`1-jan-2011`) and enddate(`31-dec-2011`) as a parameter then it must return result like

```
1-jan-2011 - 31-jan-2011
1-feb-2011 - 28-feb-2011
1-mar-2011 - 31-mar-2011
```

Please send me a stored procedure.....

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: "Please send me a stored procedure" - What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC SplitDateRange
    @from DATETIME,
    @to DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @from = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DAY, @from)+1, @from), 112)

    -- Sql 2000

    CREATE TABLE #temp (DateFrom DATETIME, DateTo DATETIME)
    WHILE @from < @to
    BEGIN
        INSERT #temp VALUES (@from, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @from)))
        SET @from = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @from)
    END

    SELECT * FROM #temp
    DROP TABLE #temp


    --sql 2005+
    /*
    ;WITH Ranges(DateFrom, DateTo) AS
    (
        SELECT @from DateFrom, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @from)) DateTo
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DateFrom), DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DateFrom)))
        FROM Ranges
        WHERE DateFrom < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @To)
    )
    SELECT * FROM Ranges
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
    */
END
GO
EXEC SplitDateRange '2011-01-02', '2012-06-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

So that you can use the results in another SQL Query *(which I assume is where you're going)* I'd put that into a table valued function.

Assuming SQL Server 2005+ you could use this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnMonthlyIntervals(
                  @from_date SMALLDATETIME,
                  @end_date  SMALLDATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH
  intervals (
    from_date,
    end_date
  )
AS
(
  SELECT @from_date,   DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @from_date  ) - 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT end_date + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, end_date + 1) - 1 FROM intervals WHERE end_date < @end_date
)
RETURN
  SELECT
    from_date,
    CASE WHEN end_date > @end_date THEN @end_date ELSE end_date END AS end_date
  FROM
    intervals
```

Then you just use `SELECT * FROM dbo.ufnMonthlyIntervals('20110101', '20111201') AS intervals`

Comment: @AndriyM - Please see the second example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx as reference for my syntax.

Comment: Yes, I see how it can be misleading when one does not pay close attention. :) The `WITH` clause between `RETURNS TABLE` and `[AS] RETURN` is **not** about CTE definition(s).